# why the used-space of "df -h" is larger than the result of "du -hs /"?

Tags: 12.04, disk-usage

the result of "df -h" shows below:

```
/dev/sda1       5.6G  3.2G  2.2G   60% /
udev            992M  4.0K  992M    1% /dev
tmpfs           401M  752K  401M    1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M    0% /run/lock
none           1002M     0 1002M    0% /run/shm
```

the result of "du -hs /" shows below:

```
1.7G    /
```

Why is that?

Comment: Is that the full output of `du -hs /`? When I run it on my computer, I do not have permissions to read many directories.

Comment: I run it under "sudo su".

Comment: Perhaps this possible dupe? http://askubuntu.com/a/79996/53508

Comment: I am afraid not. That command is to reduce the reverse space of system. but the reverse space is not large to 3.2-1.7=1.5G

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I misread the other question. Also, there the `df` used space ≈ `du` output.

Comment: Another possible dupe? http://askubuntu.com/questions/209934/why-do-df-and-du-show-different-output

Comment: I have tried...but reboot the system does nothing...

Comment: Hm, not sure, then, sorry. Hopefully someone else can help you.

Answer (score 0):

> df and du measure two different things....
>
> du reports the space used by files and folders--even this is more than
>   the file size. A few quick experiments on my system show that 4K is a
>   minimum file size in terms of disk space.
>
> df reports the space used by the file system. This includes the
>   overhead for journals and inode tables and such.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/du-vs-df-huge-difference%3B-disk-space-vanishing-539185/#post2678197