# Why are the free space and available space not the same in system monitor?

Tags: partitioning

Why are the free space and available space for the `/` and `/home` partitions not the same in system monitor? But the two are the same for the other two partitions?

In particular, my `/` and `/home` partitions are running low, and I wonder why I can't use all the free space.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [df -h shows incorrect free space](http://askubuntu.com/questions/79981/df-h-shows-incorrect-free-space)

Comment: Not going to accept one of the answers?

Answer (score 3):

After some googling I found [this post on Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-system-monitor/+question/8609) stating the following (first comment):

> The ext3 filesystem reserves an amount of the total space for root. If
>   some user (or daemon) fills the disk then a login couldn't be possible
>   anymore. So even root couldn't login anymore to fix it. Therefore ext3
>   reserves an amount of 5% (default) of the filesystem for the root user
>   to prevent it (it doesn't work if root fills the disk).
>
> Available space is now the total free space including the reserved
>   space for root. Free space is the free space that you as a user can
>   fill :)
>
> It is possible to change this with tune2fs (PLEASE consult the manpage
>   before using this tool).

Comment: I see @Sparhawk beat me to it, linking the same page. :P

Comment: Technically I beat both of you. :D This is an old question posed differently.

Comment: @muru: Technically, I didn't see your post, but you're right! :P

Comment: @Justgivemeaname +1 Google-fu FTW. :) (Also, I didn't get a notification, perhaps because I hadn't posted a comment here before.)

Comment: @muru Please type more slowly. :p (I also think it's a slightly different question, although marking it as a dupe directs people to the correct answer, so meh.)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-system-monitor/+question/8609), the system reserves 5% for root. For `/` in your screenshot, 5% of 20.2 GiB is 1.01 GiB, which is about the discrepancy.

Comment: Same thing for `/home`. 5% of 26.9 is 1.345, which works out about right. Now, I'm hoping you don't ask me about the other two partitions. :) (I *think* root might only limit it for Linux file systems.)